OpenMDAO use of "set_constraint_options()" method on Dymos Problem
In the OpenMDAO documentation page entitled Modifying Design Variables, Constraints, and Objectives
the method set_constraint_options() is documented, and in the example it is shown that the method can be called after the run_driver() method is called to change the constraint limit, and the problem can then be subsequently setup and run again.
# modify the constraint and run again
model.set_constraint_options(name='con1', upper=-1.0)
prob.setup()
prob.run_driver()
print(f"con1 = {prob.get_val('con1')}")

The documentation example code works as expected when I run it. I would like to the exact same thing, except with a Dymos problem. However, calling the set_constraint_options() method on the problem after the Dymos problem has been run with the dymos.run_problem() function returns an error.
Here is example code to show the error. Using the SSTO Earth Launch Dymos example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openmdao.api as om
import dymos as dm

#
# Setup and solve the optimal control problem
#
p = om.Problem(model=om.Group())
p.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver()
p.driver.declare_coloring(tol=1.0E-12)

from dymos.examples.ssto.launch_vehicle_ode import LaunchVehicleODE

#
# Initialize our Trajectory and Phase
#
traj = dm.Trajectory()

phase = dm.Phase(ode_class=LaunchVehicleODE, transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=12, order=3, compressed=False))

traj.add_phase("phase0", phase)
p.model.add_subsystem("traj", traj)

#
# Set the options for the variables
#
phase.set_time_options(fix_initial=True, duration_bounds=(10, 500))

phase.add_state("x", fix_initial=True, ref=1.0e5, defect_ref=10000.0, rate_source="xdot")
phase.add_state("y", fix_initial=True, ref=1.0e5, defect_ref=10000.0, rate_source="ydot")
phase.add_state("vx", fix_initial=True, ref=1.0e3, defect_ref=1000.0, rate_source="vxdot")
phase.add_state("vy", fix_initial=True, ref=1.0e3, defect_ref=1000.0, rate_source="vydot")
phase.add_state("m", fix_initial=True, ref=1.0e3, defect_ref=100.0, rate_source="mdot")

phase.add_control("theta", units="rad", lower=-1.57, upper=1.57, targets=["theta"])
phase.add_parameter("thrust", units="N", opt=False, val=2100000.0, targets=["thrust"])

#
# Set the options for our constraints and objective
#
phase.add_boundary_constraint("y", loc="final", equals=1.85e5, linear=True)
phase.add_boundary_constraint("vx", loc="final", equals=7796.6961)
phase.add_boundary_constraint("vy", loc="final", equals=0)

phase.add_objective("time", loc="final", scaler=0.01)

p.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

#
# Setup and set initial values
#
p.setup(check=True)

p.set_val("traj.phase0.t_initial", 0.0)
p.set_val("traj.phase0.t_duration", 150.0)
p.set_val("traj.phase0.states:x", phase.interp("x", [0, 1.15e5]))
p.set_val("traj.phase0.states:y", phase.interp("y", [0, 1.85e5]))
p.set_val("traj.phase0.states:vy", phase.interp("vy", [1.0e-6, 0]))
p.set_val("traj.phase0.states:m", phase.interp("m", [117000, 1163]))
p.set_val("traj.phase0.controls:theta", phase.interp("theta", [1.5, -0.76]))
p.set_val("traj.phase0.parameters:thrust", 2.1, units="MN")

#
# Solve the Problem
#
dm.run_problem(p, simulate=True)
p.model.traj.phases.phase0.set_constraint_options("timeseries.y", equals=1.80e5)

when we hit the last line, after the problem has run successfully the first time, we get the error

  File -\set_constraints_bug.py:77
    p.model.traj.phases.phase0.set_constraint_options("timeseries.y", equals=1.80e5)

  File -site-packages\openmdao\core\system.py:1106 in set_constraint_options
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(self.msginfo, name))

RuntimeError: 'traj.phases.phase0' <class Phase>: set_constraint_options called with constraint variable 'timeseries.y' that does not exist.

Now, it might be that I am not calling the method at the right level, or with the "alias" keyword variable set, but after several variations of calling it the method, I decided to see what was
going on in system.py, where set_constraint_options() lives.
The problem seem to originate in these lines of 'set_constraint_options()'
        if self._static_mode:
            responses = self._static_responses
        else:
            responses = self._responses

investigation with some debugging shows that the variable self._static_mode is True,
and the responses becomes an empty dictionary.
so when the following block of code runs
        # Look through responses to see if there are multiple responses with that name
        aliases = [resp["alias"] for resp in responses.values() if resp["name"] == name]
        if len(aliases) > 1 and alias is _UNDEFINED:
            msg = (
                "{}: set_constraint_options called with constraint variable '{}' that has "
                "multiple aliases: {}. Call set_objective_options with the 'alias' argument "
                "set to one of those aliases."
            )
            raise RuntimeError(msg.format(self.msginfo, name, aliases))

        if len(aliases) == 0:
            msg = "{}: set_constraint_options called with constraint variable '{}' that does not " "exist."
            raise RuntimeError(msg.format(self.msginfo, name))

we are looking in the empty dictionary for the constraint we want to modify.
However, the self._responses dictionary is populated, and shows the constraint we want to change:
{'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->y': {'name': 'timeseries.y', 'alias': 'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->y', 'lower': -1e+30, 'upper': 1e+30, 'equals': 185000.0, 'linear': True, 'size': 1, 'indices': ArrayIndexer: [35], 'scaler': None, 'total_scaler': None, 'adder': None, 'total_adder': None, 'ref': 1.0, 'ref0': 0.0, 'type': 'con', 'units': 'm', 'cache_linear_solution': False, 'parallel_deriv_color': None, 'flat_indices': True, 'parent': 'traj.phases.phase0', 'source': 'traj.phases.phase0.timeseries.timeseries_comp.y', 'distributed': False, 'global_size': 1}, 

'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->vx': {'name': 'timeseries.vx', 'alias': 'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->vx', 'lower': -1e+30, 'upper': 1e+30, 'equals': 7796.6961, 'linear': False, 'size': 1, 'indices': ArrayIndexer: [35], 'scaler': None, 'total_scaler': None, 'adder': None, 'total_adder': None, 'ref': 1.0, 'ref0': 0.0, 'type': 'con', 'units': 'm/s', 'cache_linear_solution': False, 'parallel_deriv_color': None, 'flat_indices': True, 'parent': 'traj.phases.phase0', 'source': 'traj.phases.phase0.timeseries.timeseries_comp.vx', 'distributed': False, 'global_size': 1}, 

'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->vy': {'name': 'timeseries.vy', 'alias': 'traj.phases.phase0->final_boundary_constraint->vy', 'lower': -1e+30, 'upper': 1e+30, 'equals': 0.0, 'linear': False, 'size': 1, 'indices': ArrayIndexer: [35], 'scaler': None, 'total_scaler': None, 'adder': None, 'total_adder': None, 'ref': 1.0, 'ref0': 0.0, 'type': 'con', 'units': 'm/s', 'cache_linear_solution': False, 'parallel_deriv_color': None, 'flat_indices': True, 'parent': 'traj.phases.phase0', 'source': 'traj.phases.phase0.timeseries.timeseries_comp.vy', 'distributed': False, 'global_size': 1}, 

't': {'name': 't', 'alias': None, 'size': 1, 'indices': IntIndexer: -1, 'scaler': 0.01, 'total_scaler': 0.01, 'adder': None, 'total_adder': None, 'ref': None, 'ref0': None, 'type': 'obj', 'units': None, 'cache_linear_solution': False, 'parallel_deriv_color': None, 'flat_indices': True, 'parent': 'traj.phases.phase0', 'source': 'traj.phases.phase0.time.t', 'distributed': False, 'global_size': 1}}

The self._static_mode flag is true and we are getting the empty self._static_responses dict
By comparison in the example problem shown in Modifying Design Variables, Constraints, and Objectives we also have self._static_mode True, but the dictionary self._static_responses is not empty so the example seems to work.
I am not sure what the static_mode flag does, as now this is getting into the guts of OpenMDAO.
It seems like I should be able to change constraint values this way, but perhaps there is some subtle thing I am missing.

This seems to be an OpenMDAO bug, working it now.

using "p._metadata["static_mode"] = False" seems to work to override the behavior, but I am probably messing with things I should not be

The crux of the issue is that we've already done the setup step, _static_responses has moved to _responses, but the Code assumes that we haven't done setup yet.  All in all its a relatively minor fix and it's going through CI on the repo now.
